# Unable to update GCP deployment using Java deployment manager SDK

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I'm trying to write an application to manage GCP deployments using the Deployment Manager SDK for Java. I'm able to list deployments successfully but unable to update a deployment as the SDK throws an exception shown below.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The object 'projects/--redacted-project--/global/deployments' is not found.",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "The object 'projects/--redacted-project--/global/deployments' is not found."
}
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1067)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
```

My calling code is:

```scala
val content = new Deployment().setTarget(target)

val updateResult = client.deployments().update(project, name, content)
          .setCreatePolicy("CREATE_OR_ACQUIRE")
          .setDeletePolicy("DELETE")
          .setPreview(false)
          .execute()
```

When I switch on debug for the SDK I see the following exchange:

```
2020-04-13 17:52:36,353 [deploy-akka.deploy-dispatcher-10] INFO  c.g.a.c.h.HttpTransport - -------------- REQUEST  --------------
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/deploymentmanager/v2/projects/--redacted-project--/global/deployments/--redacted-deployment--
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: <Not Logged>
User-Agent: Google-API-Java-Client Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.25.0 (gzip)
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 565

2020-04-13 17:52:36,353 [deploy-akka.deploy-dispatcher-10] INFO  c.g.a.c.h.HttpTransport - curl -v --compressed -X PUT -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'Authorization: <Not Logged>' -H 'User-Agent: Google-API-Java-Client Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.25.0 (gzip)' -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' -H 'Content-Encoding: gzip' -d '@-' -- 'https://www.googleapis.com/deploymentmanager/v2/projects/--redacted-project--/global/deployments/--redacted-deployment--' << $$$

2020-04-13 17:52:36,354 [deploy-akka.deploy-dispatcher-10] INFO  c.g.a.c.h.HttpTransport - Total: 1,449 bytes

2020-04-13 17:52:36,354 [deploy-akka.deploy-dispatcher-10] INFO  c.g.a.c.h.HttpTransport - {"target":{"config":{"content":"imports:\n  - path: dep.jinja\n\nresources:\n  - name: testing\n    type: dep.jinja\n    properties:\n      env: prod\n      banana: yes\n      retentionInDays: 5"},"imports":[{"content":"resources:\n- name: riffraff-dataset\n  type: bigquery.v2.dataset\n  properties:\n    location: europe-west2\n    datasetReference:\n      datasetId: riffraff_test\n- name: test-table\n  type: bigquery.v2.table\n  metadata:\n    dependsOn:\n    - riffraff-dataset\n  properties:\n    datasetId: riffraff_test\n    tableReference:\n      tableId: banana\n    schema:\n      fields:\n        - name: species\n          type: string\n        - name: plantation\n          type: string\n        - name: harvested\n          type: date\n        - name: quantity\n          type: numeric\n        - name: edible\n          type: boolean\n{% if properties['banana'] == \"yes\" %}\n- name: test-topic\n  type: gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics\n  properties:\n    topic: riffraff-topic\n{% endif %}\n- name: riffraff-bucket\n  type: storage.v1.bucket\n  properties:\n    location: europe-west2\n    storageClass: STANDARD\n    iamConfiguration:\n      uniformBucketLevelAccess:\n        enabled: True\n    {% if properties['retentionInDays'] %}\n    lifecycle:\n      rule:\n        - action:\n            type: Delete\n          condition:\n            age: {{ properties['retentionInDays'] }}\n    {% endif %}","name":"dep.jinja"}]}}

2020-04-13 17:52:37,174 [deploy-akka.deploy-dispatcher-10] INFO  c.g.a.c.h.HttpTransport - -------------- RESPONSE --------------
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2020 16:52:37 GMT
Server: ESF
Cache-Control: private
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

So it looks like an invalid URL or object.

However if I use the gcloud CLI tool to do the same thing with `--log-http` I see that it is hitting exactly the same endpoint but not getting a 404:

```
==== request start ====
uri: https://www.googleapis.com/deploymentmanager/v2/projects/--redacted-project--/global/deployments/--redacted-deployment--?alt=json&preview=False&createPolicy=CREATE_OR_ACQUIRE&deletePolicy=DELETE
method: PUT
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

After further digging I noticed that the fields in the body JSON in the PUT request were different. The `gcloud` CLI was sending `fingerprint`, `name` and `target` whilst the Java SDK was only sending `target`.

Tucked away in the [documentation for the request body](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/reference/latest/deployments#resource) it says that you need to set `fingerprint` for `update` and a handful of other methods.

I modified my code to GET the deployment first and include the `fingerprint` in the request and it began to work.

```scala
val content = new Deployment().setName(name).setFingerprint(fingerprint).setTarget(target)

val updateResult = client.deployments().update(project, name, content)
  .setCreatePolicy("CREATE_OR_ACQUIRE")
  .setDeletePolicy("DELETE")
  .setPreview(false)
  .execute()
```

In my view `404` is the wrong error for this. Google should be returning a `400` as the client is not including a required field in the request.

In addition the SDK does a large number of precondition checks to catch invalid requests but does not include this one. I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/issues/4451) with Google to suggest this.